# Negative Binomial Regression Shrinkage Priors P greater than N case

Tags: bayesian, negative-binomial-distribution, high-dimensional, regularization

Can someone suggest some literature review paper or any literature regarding Negative Binomial Regression with Shrinkage priors particularly P>N case? P: no. of variables, N: no. of observations in a dataset. Most of the work I get is for N>P case.

Comment: [Here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101031/how-does-glmnet-handle-overdispersion) it says overdispersion doesn't matter, so just use Poisson regression. Any reason why you need NB regression?

Comment: Thanks. I am working with various bayesian shrinkage priors for negbin regression, and trying to create simulation scenarios that can identify the important variables by credible intervals, particularly p>n case. So looking for literature review.