# Where does the standard error come from in Lasso?

Tags: standard-error, lasso

I'm using Lasso to get the best variables to predict an outcome. I understand that this graph gives me λmin and λ1se
[image]

However, I don't understand how to get that standard error theoretically. Where does it come from? Thank you!

Comment: SD's are not estimated, see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/91462/standard-errors-for-lasso-prediction-using-r